# Why is the eclipse swt browser not focused?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on an eclipse RCP application. I have a preference page which inherits from IWorkbenchPreferencePage. In the preference pages, I have a button which spawns a shell when clicked. The shell is always out of focus and cannot be interacted with until the preference page is disposed.

Is there any way to set the focus on the shell?

Here is some pseudo code of the prefence page:

```
public class PreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

  AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager();

  @Override
  protected void createFieldEditors() {
    final Button login = new Button(getFieldEditorParent(), SWT.PUSH);
    login.setText("Login")
    login.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent se) {
        authenticationManager.run(getShell().getDisplay());
      }
    }
  }
}

public AuthenticationManager {
  public void run(@Nullable Display optionalDisplay) {
    display.asyncExec(() -> {
      // set the url & add listeners
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you creating the Shell? What is the parent of the shell? The preference dialog is application modal only a shell which has the dialog as its parent will be able to have focus.

Comment: If you want to progress with this question you need to answer the questions in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by passing the shell rather than display. I still can't find the appropriate swt documentation for why this works but anyway, here's what my solution looks like now:

```
public class PreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

  AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager();

  @Override
  protected void createFieldEditors() {
    final Button login = new Button(getFieldEditorParent(), SWT.PUSH);
    login.setText("Login")
    login.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent se) {
        authenticationManager.run(getShell());
      }
    }
  }
}

public AuthenticationManager {
  public void run(@Nullable Shell optionalShell) {
    final Display display;
    if (optionalShell == null) {
        if (PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning()) {
            display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();
        } else {
            display = null;
        }
    } else {
        display = optionalShell.getDisplay();
    }


    display.syncExec(() -> {
      // set the url & add listeners
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Presumably you are using the Shell as the parent of the dialog you create. This works because the preference dialog specifies `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL` in its style - only a dialog which has the application modal dialog as its parent can have focus.